# 16.04 display resolution setting won't stick

Tags: 16.04, display-resolution

I'm using the menu

```
System Tools -> System Settings -> Displays
```

to change my screen resolution from

```
1920 x 1080 (16:9)
```

to

```
1368 x 768 (16:9)
```

This is so the windows and the text in them will be roughly the same size if I move them between the laptop screen and an external display monitor.
This works fine when I do it, it asks me if I want to keep the resolution configuration and I click the button to do so.

The problem is that if I log off or reboot, the resolution is reset to the 1920x1080 default.

Comment: This looks like a persistent problem with Ubuntu, there have been identical posts with prior levels. I tried adding the line  
  
    "xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode 1360x768"  
  
to the Startup Applications Preferences menu, but it didn't work.

Comment: Note that this problem differs from most of the prior posts, though, given that the menu is showing the correct settings options, and changing the resolution accomplishes what I want, it just doesn't "stick".

Comment: When I did a "Restart" instead of my usual "Power Off", it looks like the resolution settings stuck this time. This solves the problem from my end, but I'm puzzled why it happens. My guess is that the settings are not being written to the right place or somehow there's a temporary settings file that gets clobbered during the Power Off, but the settings are moved to permanent with the Restart.

Comment: One other note -- after re-running "detect displays" (I was trying to get a projector working) I had to go back through the process again. I'm using a Dell Latitude E7470. When I look at how the cursor behaves when I get close to the screen boundary, I suspect that the 16:9 or 1360x768 resolution may not be exactly correct, so the Display manager may try to ignore the setting in place and fall back to a default.

Comment: I had to re-install my laptop and am back to square-one on this.
Just using "Restart" wasn't enough to get it to stick.
The first time, there may have been some partial settings in place from my trial-and-error experiments with xrandr etc. and I haven't gotten back to this state.
One thing I have to mentio, if I run the command

sudo unity-control-center display

I get to a similar menu with more options, but can't get it to work because of this message:

"GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon was not provided by any .service files"

Comment: Ok here's the missing info -- the laptop had to be un-docked for the setting to stick. When I also have an external monitor attached, the settings still gets reset when I reboot or restart. I don't know whether or not it will work if I use a dock without the external monitor.

Comment: So in summary: (1) Boot up the laptop *undocked* and log in. (2) Use the [System Tools] -> [System Settings] -> [Displays] to set the resolution. (3) Accept the new resolution and close the menus. (4) Restart the laptop.

Note that this a a *workaround* not a *fix*. Your resolution should be okay after this, but there's something really wrong with the system configuration management that you have to do this. Can anyone figure out what the real problem is here?